# How do I make WHERE IN not a string?

Tags: mysql

I have a subquery where my IN expression is coming from a column in the main table.  MySQL is seeing this column as a string.  How do I fix?

So for instance, my query is being interpreted as:

```
SELECT song.title, 
    (SELECT group_concat(username) FROM users WHERE user_id IN ('4,9')) as editors 
FROM songs song WHERE ...
```

The '4,9' is coming from my songs table column called editors_list which is a CSV of user_ids.

So MySQL is only doing a match on the user_id of 4.  How can I make MySQL look at songs.editors_list as 4,9 so that the query looks like:

```
SELECT song.title, 
    (SELECT group_concat(username) FROM users WHERE user_id IN (4,9)) as editors 
FROM songs song WHERE ...
```

and therefore it matches on user_id = 4 and user_id = 9

My current query looks like:

```
SELECT song.title, 
    (SELECT group_concat(username) FROM users WHERE user_id IN (song.editors_list)) as editors 
FROM songs song WHERE ...
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use a group_concat and then filter the data in it. What is your current schema and what is your expected result? Sample data would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has a built-in function that allows you to search a value inside a csv format called `FIND_IN_SET()`.

```
SELECT a.title, 
       group_concat(b.username) 
FROM   songs a
       INNER JOIN b
          ON FIND_IN_SET(b.user_id, a.editors_list) > 0
WHERE ...
GROUP  BY a.title
```

- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: +1 and I was going to use regex with a yoda test :/ this is of course the right answer

Comment: Am I able to do something like this with additional joins?  have a couple left joins in my query too.